# How to set up perfectly multiple figures when using subfigure and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats, resize

I have the next latex script. I want to align up perfectly the borders (bounds) of each plot with respect to the others, basically guaranteeing that the real space (i.e., over the paper) used for each plot inside the borders is the same for all of the plots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\definecolor{clr1}{RGB}{200,95,100}
\definecolor{clr2}{RGB}{45,50,140}
\definecolor{clr3}{RGB}{80,120,200}
\definecolor{clr4}{RGB}{237,125,49}
\definecolor{clr5}{RGB}{0,150,80}
\definecolor{clr6}{RGB}{40,115,50}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
        \centering
        \subfigure[][\textcolor{white}{------ ------- ------ -------}]
        {
            \resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        clip=false,
                        legend style={font=\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont},
                        label style={font=\scriptsize},
                        legend pos=north west,
                        ymin=0,ymax=4,
                        xmin=0,xmax=15,
                        ylabel={y axis},
                        ytick={0, 1,2,3,4},
                        xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
                        xticklabels={1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4},
                        yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4},
                        major tick length=0,
                        legend cell align={left}] 
                        \addplot+[color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1.29473568215357) (3,1.39833253427866) (4,2.10045736031047) }; %-0.594370123325565
                        \addplot+[color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(6,0.770412199527345) (7,0.952801038146577) (8,1.19450635236477) (9,2.07855099622044) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(11,1.03620956057027) (12,1.70642493928102) (13,1.79141496697919) (14,2.56162632971291) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(1,0.213619006477657) (2,0.616230901392108) (3,0.76959974210965) (4,2.15867519087421) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(6,0.723849628183581) (7,1.05434729307198) (8,1.8012477694615) (9,2.40938275350106) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(11,0.138619809118684) (12,1.1208100701975) (13,1.71915892721322) (14,2.67999683211968) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(1,0.377380046518835) (2,1.26906172026593) (3,1.55158250609981) (4,2.71967226601291) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(6,0.485709709069876) (7,1.54291829624409) (8,1.29475696806193) (9,2.54479934836371) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(11,1.46477498149735) (12,1.86920930768715) (13,2.21198709272709) (14,3.13789640125608) };
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr1,thick} \addlegendentry{Chi Square}
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr2,thick} \addlegendentry{Normal}
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr3,thick} \addlegendentry{Power Law}
                        \node[] at (axis cs:2.5,-0.6) {$\alpha$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5,-0.6) {$\beta$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:12.5,-0.6) {$\gamma$};
                        \draw[] (axis cs:5,-0) -- (axis cs:5,-0.7);
                        \draw[] (axis cs:10,-0) -- (axis cs:10,-0.7);
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5, -1) {$\phi$,$\omega$};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }
        \subfigure[][\textcolor{white}{------ ------- ------ -------}]
        {
            \resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        clip=false,
                        legend style={font=\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont},
                        label style={font=\scriptsize},
                        legend pos=north west,
                        ymin=0,ymax=80,
                        xmin=0,xmax=15,
                        ylabel={y axis},
                        ytick={0,20,40,60,80},
                        xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
                        xticklabels={1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4},
                        yticklabels={0,20,40,60,80},
                        major tick length=0,
                        legend cell align={left}] 
                        \addplot+[name path=min1,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.36539893223641) (2,14.5211533779555) (3,21.8006831491548) (4,28.902581369331) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min2,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.6253771683284) (7,21.2839604333547) (8,31.9027496251708) (9,42.2090228011179) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min3,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.2808977792486) (12,32.4309066871019) (13,48.6659880368873) (14,64.443596410537) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg1,color=clr4, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.47701666666675) (2,14.6751466666664) (3,21.9902299999995) (4,29.1186766666663) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg2,color=clr4, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.7545666666665) (7,21.4702733333327) (8,32.1284866666666) (9,42.4669866666667) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg3,color=clr4, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.4294133333329) (12,32.6422966666667) (13,48.9225633333329) (14,64.740223333333) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up1,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.58863440109709) (2,14.8291399553773) (3,22.1797768508442) (4,29.3347719640016) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up2,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.8837561650046) (7,21.6565862333107) (8,32.3542237081624) (9,42.7249505322155) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up3,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.5779288874172) (12,32.8536866462315) (13,49.1791386297785) (14,65.0368502561291) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min1,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,6.42565252286121) (2,13.4442847377938) (3,20.5364543773529) (4,27.5930763112943) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min2,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,9.91647866191362) (7,20.5835861899945) (8,31.2827499741228) (9,42.1804208227532) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min3,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,15.6954568766562) (12,32.3754678982564) (13,48.8473714625863) (14,65.361138513811) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg1,color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.43257551348401) (2,14.8651510269681) (3,22.2977265404522) (4,29.7303020539363) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg2,color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.8374211602728) (7,21.6748423205456) (8,32.5122634808186) (9,43.3496846410915) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg3,color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.5996564850385) (12,33.1993129577408) (13,49.7989694551161) (14,66.3986259401546) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up1,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,8.43949850410681) (2,16.2860173161424) (3,24.0589987035515) (4,31.8675277965783) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up2,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,11.758363658632) (7,22.7660984510967) (8,33.7417769875144) (9,44.5189484594298) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up3,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,17.5038560934208) (12,34.0231580172252) (13,50.7505674476459) (14,67.4361133664982) };
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr1,thick} \addlegendentry{method 1}
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr4,thick} \addlegendentry{method 2}
                        \addplot[clr4!30] fill between[of=up1 and min1];
                        \addplot[clr4!30] fill between[of=up2 and min2];
                        \addplot[clr4!30] fill between[of=up3 and min3];
                        \addplot[clr1!30] fill between[of=2up1 and 2min1];
                        \addplot[clr1!30] fill between[of=2up2 and 2min2];
                        \addplot[clr1!30] fill between[of=2up3 and 2min3];
                        \node[] at (axis cs:2.5,-12) {$\alpha$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5,-12) {$\beta$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:12.5,-12) {$\gamma$};
                        \draw[] (axis cs:5,0) -- (axis cs:5,-14);
                        \draw[] (axis cs:10,0) -- (axis cs:10,-14);
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5, -20) {$\phi$,$\omega$};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }  
        }
        \subfigure[][\textcolor{white}{------ ------- ------ -------}]
        {%
            \resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        clip=false,
                        legend style={font=\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont},
                        label style={font=\scriptsize},
                        legend pos=north west,
                        ymin=0,ymax=80,
                        xmin=0,xmax=15,
                        ylabel={y axis},
                        ytick={0,20,40,60,80},
                        xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
                        xticklabels={1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4},
                        yticklabels={0,20,40,60,80},
                        major tick length=0,
                        legend cell align={left}] 
                        \addplot+[name path=min1,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.31000269872584) (2,14.6234759067486) (3,21.9443750583858) (4,28.8989591258725) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min2,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.6855236003467) (7,21.3772591410606) (8,31.8790940002111) (9,42.3007866958399) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min3,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.4399175378288) (12,32.6461975572842) (13,48.7369484470698) (14,64.4241565150957) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg1,color=clr5, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.42104000000005) (2,14.7826899999998) (3,22.1402866666662) (4,29.1189866666664) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg2,color=clr5, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.8179366666665) (7,21.5651133333328) (8,32.1103399999997) (9,42.5595466666666) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg3,color=clr5, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.5914433333329) (12,32.8605799999998) (13,49.0009233333333) (14,64.7231899999999) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up1,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.53207730127426) (2,14.941904093251) (3,22.3361982749466) (4,29.3390142074603) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up2,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.9503497329863) (7,21.752967525605) (8,32.3415859997883) (9,42.8183066374933) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up3,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.742969128837) (12,33.0749624427154) (13,49.2648982195968) (14,65.0222234849041) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min1,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,6.39715413992785) (2,13.3952847056687) (3,20.8434482535011) (4,28.2606184031996) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min2,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,9.99618082766089) (7,20.7884972514443) (8,31.4740953985945) (9,42.4483947015957) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min3,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,15.7762258652082) (12,32.3333629743261) (13,48.8492179815856) (14,65.3613766312979) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg1,color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.43689275191836) (2,14.8737855038368) (3,22.3106782557552) (4,29.7475710076737) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg2,color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.8962422610053) (7,21.7924845220107) (8,32.6887267830162) (9,43.5849690440215) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg3,color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.6144423604116) (12,33.2288846897651) (13,49.8433270812352) (14,66.4577694416467) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up1,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,8.47663136390887) (2,16.3522863020049) (3,23.7779082580093) (4,31.2345236121478) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up2,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,11.7963036943497) (7,22.7964717925771) (8,33.9033581674379) (9,44.7215433864473) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up3,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,17.452658855615) (12,34.1244064052042) (13,50.8374361808848) (14,67.5541622519955) };
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr2,thick} \addlegendentry{method 1}
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr5,thick} \addlegendentry{method 2}
                        \addplot[clr5!30] fill between[of=up1 and min1];
                        \addplot[clr5!30] fill between[of=up2 and min2];
                        \addplot[clr5!30] fill between[of=up3 and min3];
                        \addplot[clr2!30] fill between[of=2up1 and 2min1];
                        \addplot[clr2!30] fill between[of=2up2 and 2min2];
                        \addplot[clr2!30] fill between[of=2up3 and 2min3];
                        \node[] at (axis cs:2.5,-12) {$\alpha$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5,-12) {$\beta$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:12.5,-12) {$\gamma$};
                        \draw[] (axis cs:5,0) -- (axis cs:5,-14);
                        \draw[] (axis cs:10,0) -- (axis cs:10,-14);
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5, -20) {$\phi$,$\omega$};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }
        \subfigure[][\textcolor{white}{------ ------- ------ -------}]
        {%
            \resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \begin{axis}[
                        clip=false,
                        legend style={font=\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont},
                        label style={font=\scriptsize},
                        legend pos=north west,
                        ymin=0,ymax=80,
                        xmin=0,xmax=15,
                        ylabel={y axis},
                        ytick={0,20,40,60,80},
                        xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
                        xticklabels={1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4},
                        yticklabels={0,20,40,60,80},
                        major tick length=0,
                        legend cell align={left}] 
                        \addplot+[name path=min1,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.2617232766601) (2,14.4680749092339) (3,21.6871818386066) (4,28.6235229337246) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min2,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.4466564581329) (7,20.7550717502665) (8,31.2585866911777) (9,41.2167137846509) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min3,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.236658999683) (12,32.4366974815625) (13,48.5535530086021) (14,64.2037285516522) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg1,color=clr6, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.38116000000005) (2,14.6323366666664) (3,21.8874433333327) (4,28.8513966666664) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg2,color=clr6, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.5811433333332) (7,20.9419566666662) (8,31.4898933333331) (9,41.4746999999999) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg3,color=clr6, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.3936566666664) (12,32.6571433333333) (13,48.8214366666666) (14,64.5108633333335) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up1,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.50059672334) (2,14.7965984240989) (3,22.0877048280588) (4,29.0792703996082) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up2,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.7156302085335) (7,21.1288415830659) (8,31.7211999754885) (9,41.7326862153489) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up3,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.5506543336498) (12,32.8775891851041) (13,49.0893203247311) (14,64.8179981150148) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min1,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,6.35327922467375) (2,13.2744239387005) (3,20.2717978423772) (4,27.7248848189148) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min2,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,9.58669927080587) (7,20.1057231186807) (8,30.76238054228) (9,41.2581975426363) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min3,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,15.7537659514287) (12,32.3582144477746) (13,48.8744039249612) (14,65.5343006488307) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg1,color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.40901502504168) (2,14.8180300500835) (3,22.2270450751252) (4,29.6360601001671) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg2,color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.6325369738338) (7,21.2650739476677) (8,31.8976109215017) (9,42.5301478953357) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg3,color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.6337868480723) (12,33.2675736961447) (13,49.9013605442172) (14,66.5351473922894) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up1,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,8.46475082540961) (2,16.3616361614665) (3,24.1822923078732) (4,31.5472353814194) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up2,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,11.6783746768617) (7,22.4244247766547) (8,33.0328413007234) (9,43.8020982480351) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up3,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,17.5138077447159) (12,34.1769329445148) (13,50.9283171634732) (14,67.5359941357481) };
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr3,thick} \addlegendentry{method 1}
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr6,thick} \addlegendentry{method 2}
                        \addplot[clr6!30] fill between[of=up1 and min1];
                        \addplot[clr6!30] fill between[of=up2 and min2];
                        \addplot[clr6!30] fill between[of=up3 and min3];
                        \addplot[clr3!30] fill between[of=2up1 and 2min1];
                        \addplot[clr3!30] fill between[of=2up2 and 2min2];
                        \addplot[clr3!30] fill between[of=2up3 and 2min3];
                        \node[] at (axis cs:2.5,-12) {$\alpha$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5,-12) {$\beta$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:12.5,-12) {$\gamma$};
                        \draw[] (axis cs:5,0) -- (axis cs:5,-14);
                        \draw[] (axis cs:10,0) -- (axis cs:10,-14);
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5, -20) {$\phi$,$\omega$};
                    \end{axis}
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        }
    \caption{bla bla bla}   
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you, by chance, looking for `group plots`?

Comment: Note that the `subfigure` package is considered deprecated. Is it an option to load the `caption` package by the way? (I see you have `caption=false`)

Comment: The groupplot environment of pgfplots (section 5.8) does this sort of thing, but does not include subcaptions.  You could add them yourself, especially if you are willing to type (a) (b) ... instead of using a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a groupplot version.  As always, the `width` parameter is more of a suggestion than a rule.  One can always scale it to precisely `\textwidth` if so desired.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% not used here
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,groupplots}
\definecolor{clr1}{RGB}{200,95,100}
\definecolor{clr2}{RGB}{45,50,140}
\definecolor{clr3}{RGB}{80,120,200}
\definecolor{clr4}{RGB}{237,125,49}
\definecolor{clr5}{RGB}{0,150,80}
\definecolor{clr6}{RGB}{40,115,50}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}[every axis title/.style={at={(0.5,-1.4cm)},below}]% axis relative coordinates
              \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2, x descriptions at=all, y descriptions at=all, vertical sep=1.5cm},
                width=0.5\textwidth,
                ]
              \nextgroupplot[
                        clip=false,
                        legend style={font=\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont},
                        label style={font=\scriptsize},
                        legend pos=north west,
                        ymin=0,ymax=4,
                        xmin=0,xmax=15,
                        ylabel={y axis},
                        ytick={0, 1,2,3,4},
                        xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
                        xticklabels={1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4},
                        yticklabels={0,1,2,3,4},
                        major tick length=0,
                        legend cell align={left}] 
                        \addplot+[color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(1,0) (2,1.29473568215357) (3,1.39833253427866) (4,2.10045736031047) }; %-0.594370123325565
                        \addplot+[color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(6,0.770412199527345) (7,0.952801038146577) (8,1.19450635236477) (9,2.07855099622044) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(11,1.03620956057027) (12,1.70642493928102) (13,1.79141496697919) (14,2.56162632971291) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(1,0.213619006477657) (2,0.616230901392108) (3,0.76959974210965) (4,2.15867519087421) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(6,0.723849628183581) (7,1.05434729307198) (8,1.8012477694615) (9,2.40938275350106) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(11,0.138619809118684) (12,1.1208100701975) (13,1.71915892721322) (14,2.67999683211968) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(1,0.377380046518835) (2,1.26906172026593) (3,1.55158250609981) (4,2.71967226601291) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(6,0.485709709069876) (7,1.54291829624409) (8,1.29475696806193) (9,2.54479934836371) };
                        \addplot+[color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot, thick] coordinates {(11,1.46477498149735) (12,1.86920930768715) (13,2.21198709272709) (14,3.13789640125608) };
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr1,thick} \addlegendentry{Chi Square}
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr2,thick} \addlegendentry{Normal}
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr3,thick} \addlegendentry{Power Law}
                        \node[] at (axis cs:2.5,-0.6) {$\alpha$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5,-0.6) {$\beta$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:12.5,-0.6) {$\gamma$};
                        \draw[] (axis cs:5,-0) -- (axis cs:5,-0.7);
                        \draw[] (axis cs:10,-0) -- (axis cs:10,-0.7);
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5, -1) {$\phi$,$\omega$};
              \nextgroupplot[
                        clip=false,
                        legend style={font=\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont},
                        label style={font=\scriptsize},
                        legend pos=north west,
                        ymin=0,ymax=80,
                        xmin=0,xmax=15,
                        ylabel={y axis},
                        ytick={0,20,40,60,80},
                        xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
                        xticklabels={1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4},
                        yticklabels={0,20,40,60,80},
                        major tick length=0,
                        legend cell align={left}] 
                        \addplot+[name path=min1,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.36539893223641) (2,14.5211533779555) (3,21.8006831491548) (4,28.902581369331) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min2,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.6253771683284) (7,21.2839604333547) (8,31.9027496251708) (9,42.2090228011179) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min3,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.2808977792486) (12,32.4309066871019) (13,48.6659880368873) (14,64.443596410537) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg1,color=clr4, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.47701666666675) (2,14.6751466666664) (3,21.9902299999995) (4,29.1186766666663) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg2,color=clr4, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.7545666666665) (7,21.4702733333327) (8,32.1284866666666) (9,42.4669866666667) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg3,color=clr4, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.4294133333329) (12,32.6422966666667) (13,48.9225633333329) (14,64.740223333333) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up1,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.58863440109709) (2,14.8291399553773) (3,22.1797768508442) (4,29.3347719640016) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up2,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.8837561650046) (7,21.6565862333107) (8,32.3542237081624) (9,42.7249505322155) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up3,color=clr4!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.5779288874172) (12,32.8536866462315) (13,49.1791386297785) (14,65.0368502561291) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min1,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,6.42565252286121) (2,13.4442847377938) (3,20.5364543773529) (4,27.5930763112943) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min2,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,9.91647866191362) (7,20.5835861899945) (8,31.2827499741228) (9,42.1804208227532) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min3,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,15.6954568766562) (12,32.3754678982564) (13,48.8473714625863) (14,65.361138513811) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg1,color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.43257551348401) (2,14.8651510269681) (3,22.2977265404522) (4,29.7303020539363) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg2,color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.8374211602728) (7,21.6748423205456) (8,32.5122634808186) (9,43.3496846410915) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg3,color=clr1, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.5996564850385) (12,33.1993129577408) (13,49.7989694551161) (14,66.3986259401546) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up1,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,8.43949850410681) (2,16.2860173161424) (3,24.0589987035515) (4,31.8675277965783) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up2,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,11.758363658632) (7,22.7660984510967) (8,33.7417769875144) (9,44.5189484594298) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up3,color=clr1!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,17.5038560934208) (12,34.0231580172252) (13,50.7505674476459) (14,67.4361133664982) };
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr1,thick} \addlegendentry{method 1}
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr4,thick} \addlegendentry{method 2}
                        \addplot[clr4!30] fill between[of=up1 and min1];
                        \addplot[clr4!30] fill between[of=up2 and min2];
                        \addplot[clr4!30] fill between[of=up3 and min3];
                        \addplot[clr1!30] fill between[of=2up1 and 2min1];
                        \addplot[clr1!30] fill between[of=2up2 and 2min2];
                        \addplot[clr1!30] fill between[of=2up3 and 2min3];
                        \node[] at (axis cs:2.5,-12) {$\alpha$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5,-12) {$\beta$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:12.5,-12) {$\gamma$};
                        \draw[] (axis cs:5,0) -- (axis cs:5,-14);
                        \draw[] (axis cs:10,0) -- (axis cs:10,-14);
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5, -20) {$\phi$,$\omega$};
              \nextgroupplot[
                        clip=false,
                        legend style={font=\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont},
                        label style={font=\scriptsize},
                        legend pos=north west,
                        ymin=0,ymax=80,
                        xmin=0,xmax=15,
                        ylabel={y axis},
                        ytick={0,20,40,60,80},
                        xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
                        xticklabels={1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4},
                        yticklabels={0,20,40,60,80},
                        major tick length=0,
                        legend cell align={left}] 
                        \addplot+[name path=min1,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.31000269872584) (2,14.6234759067486) (3,21.9443750583858) (4,28.8989591258725) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min2,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.6855236003467) (7,21.3772591410606) (8,31.8790940002111) (9,42.3007866958399) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min3,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.4399175378288) (12,32.6461975572842) (13,48.7369484470698) (14,64.4241565150957) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg1,color=clr5, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.42104000000005) (2,14.7826899999998) (3,22.1402866666662) (4,29.1189866666664) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg2,color=clr5, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.8179366666665) (7,21.5651133333328) (8,32.1103399999997) (9,42.5595466666666) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg3,color=clr5, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.5914433333329) (12,32.8605799999998) (13,49.0009233333333) (14,64.7231899999999) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up1,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.53207730127426) (2,14.941904093251) (3,22.3361982749466) (4,29.3390142074603) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up2,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.9503497329863) (7,21.752967525605) (8,32.3415859997883) (9,42.8183066374933) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up3,color=clr5!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.742969128837) (12,33.0749624427154) (13,49.2648982195968) (14,65.0222234849041) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min1,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,6.39715413992785) (2,13.3952847056687) (3,20.8434482535011) (4,28.2606184031996) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min2,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,9.99618082766089) (7,20.7884972514443) (8,31.4740953985945) (9,42.4483947015957) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min3,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,15.7762258652082) (12,32.3333629743261) (13,48.8492179815856) (14,65.3613766312979) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg1,color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.43689275191836) (2,14.8737855038368) (3,22.3106782557552) (4,29.7475710076737) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg2,color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.8962422610053) (7,21.7924845220107) (8,32.6887267830162) (9,43.5849690440215) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg3,color=clr2, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.6144423604116) (12,33.2288846897651) (13,49.8433270812352) (14,66.4577694416467) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up1,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,8.47663136390887) (2,16.3522863020049) (3,23.7779082580093) (4,31.2345236121478) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up2,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,11.7963036943497) (7,22.7964717925771) (8,33.9033581674379) (9,44.7215433864473) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up3,color=clr2!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,17.452658855615) (12,34.1244064052042) (13,50.8374361808848) (14,67.5541622519955) };
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr2,thick} \addlegendentry{method 1}
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr5,thick} \addlegendentry{method 2}
                        \addplot[clr5!30] fill between[of=up1 and min1];
                        \addplot[clr5!30] fill between[of=up2 and min2];
                        \addplot[clr5!30] fill between[of=up3 and min3];
                        \addplot[clr2!30] fill between[of=2up1 and 2min1];
                        \addplot[clr2!30] fill between[of=2up2 and 2min2];
                        \addplot[clr2!30] fill between[of=2up3 and 2min3];
                        \node[] at (axis cs:2.5,-12) {$\alpha$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5,-12) {$\beta$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:12.5,-12) {$\gamma$};
                        \draw[] (axis cs:5,0) -- (axis cs:5,-14);
                        \draw[] (axis cs:10,0) -- (axis cs:10,-14);
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5, -20) {$\phi$,$\omega$};
              \nextgroupplot[
                        clip=false,
                        legend style={font=\fontsize{4}{4}\selectfont},
                        label style={font=\scriptsize},
                        legend pos=north west,
                        ymin=0,ymax=80,
                        xmin=0,xmax=15,
                        ylabel={y axis},
                        ytick={0,20,40,60,80},
                        xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
                        xticklabels={1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4},
                        yticklabels={0,20,40,60,80},
                        major tick length=0,
                        legend cell align={left}] 
                        \addplot+[name path=min1,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.2617232766601) (2,14.4680749092339) (3,21.6871818386066) (4,28.6235229337246) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min2,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.4466564581329) (7,20.7550717502665) (8,31.2585866911777) (9,41.2167137846509) };
                        \addplot+[name path=min3,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.236658999683) (12,32.4366974815625) (13,48.5535530086021) (14,64.2037285516522) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg1,color=clr6, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.38116000000005) (2,14.6323366666664) (3,21.8874433333327) (4,28.8513966666664) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg2,color=clr6, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.5811433333332) (7,20.9419566666662) (8,31.4898933333331) (9,41.4746999999999) };
                        \addplot+[name path=avg3,color=clr6, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.3936566666664) (12,32.6571433333333) (13,48.8214366666666) (14,64.5108633333335) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up1,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,7.50059672334) (2,14.7965984240989) (3,22.0877048280588) (4,29.0792703996082) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up2,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,10.7156302085335) (7,21.1288415830659) (8,31.7211999754885) (9,41.7326862153489) };
                        \addplot+[name path=up3,color=clr6!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,16.5506543336498) (12,32.8775891851041) (13,49.0893203247311) (14,64.8179981150148) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min1,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,6.35327922467375) (2,13.2744239387005) (3,20.2717978423772) (4,27.7248848189148) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min2,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,9.58669927080587) (7,20.1057231186807) (8,30.76238054228) (9,41.2581975426363) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2min3,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,15.7537659514287) (12,32.3582144477746) (13,48.8744039249612) (14,65.5343006488307) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg1,color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(1,7.40901502504168) (2,14.8180300500835) (3,22.2270450751252) (4,29.6360601001671) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg2,color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(6,10.6325369738338) (7,21.2650739476677) (8,31.8976109215017) (9,42.5301478953357) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2avg3,color=clr3, mark=none, forget plot] coordinates {(11,16.6337868480723) (12,33.2675736961447) (13,49.9013605442172) (14,66.5351473922894) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up1,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(1,8.46475082540961) (2,16.3616361614665) (3,24.1822923078732) (4,31.5472353814194) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up2,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(6,11.6783746768617) (7,22.4244247766547) (8,33.0328413007234) (9,43.8020982480351) };
                        \addplot+[name path=2up3,color=clr3!30, mark=none, forget plot,line width=0.0mm] coordinates {(11,17.5138077447159) (12,34.1769329445148) (13,50.9283171634732) (14,67.5359941357481) };
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr3,thick} \addlegendentry{method 1}
                        \addlegendimage{color=clr6,thick} \addlegendentry{method 2}
                        \addplot[clr6!30] fill between[of=up1 and min1];
                        \addplot[clr6!30] fill between[of=up2 and min2];
                        \addplot[clr6!30] fill between[of=up3 and min3];
                        \addplot[clr3!30] fill between[of=2up1 and 2min1];
                        \addplot[clr3!30] fill between[of=2up2 and 2min2];
                        \addplot[clr3!30] fill between[of=2up3 and 2min3];
                        \node[] at (axis cs:2.5,-12) {$\alpha$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5,-12) {$\beta$};
                        \node[] at (axis cs:12.5,-12) {$\gamma$};
                        \draw[] (axis cs:5,0) -- (axis cs:5,-14);
                        \draw[] (axis cs:10,0) -- (axis cs:10,-14);
                        \node[] at (axis cs:7.5, -20) {$\phi$,$\omega$};
                  \end{groupplot}
                  \draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);% tikzpicture boundary
                \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{bla bla bla}   
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

see, if this solution fulfill your expectation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}
\definecolor{clr1}{RGB}{200,95,100}
\definecolor{clr2}{RGB}{45,50,140}
\definecolor{clr3}{RGB}{80,120,200}
\definecolor{clr4}{RGB}{237,125,49}
\definecolor{clr5}{RGB}{0,150,80}
\definecolor{clr6}{RGB}{40,115,50}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,
                 width=0.48\linewidth,
                 legend style = {font=\tiny},
                 label style = {font=\scriptsize},
                 legend pos = north west,
                 legend cell align = {left},
                 y label style = {at={(-8mm,0.5)},anchor=east},
                 x label style = {at={(0.5,-8mm)},anchor=north},
                 no marks,
                 every axis plot post/.append style={thick},
                 xmin=0,xmax=15,
                 xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
                 xticklabels={1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4,,1,2,3,4},
                 clip=false
                }% end of common pgfplots set
\tikzset{X/.style = {below, font=\scriptsize}}
\subfloat[]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel={y axis},
    xlabel={$\phi, \psi$},
    ymin=0, ymax=4,
            ]
\addplot+[color=clr1] coordinates
    {(1,0) (2,1.29) (3,1.39) (4,2.10) }; %-0.594370123325565
\addplot+[color=clr1] coordinates
    {(6,0.77) (7,0.95) (8,1.19) (9,2.08) };
\addplot+[color=clr1] coordinates
    {(11,1.04) (12,1.71) (13,1.80) (14,2.56) };
\addplot+[color=clr2] coordinates
    {(1,0.21) (2,0.61) (3,0.77) (4,2.16) };
\addplot+[color=clr2] coordinates
    {(6,0.72) (7,1.05) (8,1.80) (9,2.40) };
\addplot+[color=clr2] coordinates
    {(11,0.14) (12,1.12) (13,1.72) (14,2.68) };
\addplot+[color=clr3] coordinates
    {(1,0.38) (2,1.27) (3,1.55) (4,2.72) };
\addplot+[color=clr3] coordinates
    {(6,0.48) (7,1.54) (8,1.30) (9,2.54) };
\addplot+[color=clr3] coordinates
    {(11,1.46) (12,1.87) (13,2.21) (14,3.14) };
\legend{Chi Square, Normal, Power Law}
    \draw   ( 5,0) -- ++ (0,-0.7)
            (10,0) -- ++ (0,-0.7);
\node[X]   at ( 2.5,-0.6) {$\alpha$};
\node[X]   at ( 7.5,-0.6) {$\beta$};
\node[X]   at (12.5,-0.6) {$\gamma$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
            }
\hfill
\subfloat[]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel={y axis},
    xlabel={$\phi, \psi$},
    ymin=0, ymax=80,
            ]
\addplot+[name path=min1,draw=none] coordinates
    {(1,7.36) (2,14.52) (3,21.80) (4,28.90) };
 \addplot+[name path=min2,draw=none] coordinates
    {(6,10.624) (7,21.28) (8,31.90) (9,42.20) };
\addplot+[name path=min3,draw=none] coordinates
    {(11,16.28) (12,32.43) (13,48.66) (14,64.44) };
%
\addplot+[name path=avg1,color=clr4] coordinates
    {(1,7.48) (2,14.67) (3,22.00) (4,29.12) };
\addplot+[name path=avg2,color=clr4] coordinates
    {(6,10.75) (7,21.47) (8,32.136) (9,42.47) };
\addplot+[name path=avg3,color=clr4] coordinates
    {(11,16.43) (12,32.64) (13,48.92) (14,64.74) };
%%
\addplot+[name path=up1,draw=none] coordinates
    {(1,7.59) (2,14.83) (3,22.18) (4,29.33) };
\addplot+[name path=up2,draw=none] coordinates
    {(6,10.88) (7,21.66) (8,32.35) (9,42.72) };
\addplot+[name path=up3,draw=none] coordinates
    {(11,16.58) (12,32.85) (13,49.18) (14,65.04) };
%
\addplot+[name path=2min1,draw=none] coordinates
    {(1,6.42) (2,13.44) (3,20.54) (4,27.59) };
\addplot+[name path=2min2,draw=none] coordinates
    {(6,9.92) (7,20.58) (8,31.28) (9,42.18) };
\addplot+[name path=2min3,draw=none] coordinates
    {(11,15.69) (12,32.37) (13,48.85) (14,65.36) };
%
\addplot+[name path=2avg1,color=clr1] coordinates
    {(1,7.43) (2,14.86) (3,22.30) (4,29.73) };
\addplot+[name path=2avg2,color=clr1] coordinates
    {(6,10.84) (7,21.67) (8,32.51) (9,43.35) };
\addplot+[name path=2avg3,color=clr1] coordinates
    {(11,16.60) (12,33.20) (13,49.80) (14,66.40) };
%
\addplot+[name path=2up1,draw=none] coordinates
    {(1,8.44) (2,16.29) (3,24.06) (4,31.87) };
\addplot+[name path=2up2,draw=none] coordinates
    {(6,11.7583636586326) (7,22.77) (8,33.74) (9,44.52) };
\addplot+[name path=2up3,draw=none] coordinates
    {(11,17.50) (12,34.02) (13,50.75) (14,67.44) };
\addplot[clr4!30] fill between[of=up1 and min1];
\addplot[clr4!30] fill between[of=up2 and min2];
\addplot[clr4!30] fill between[of=up3 and min3];
\addplot[clr1!30] fill between[of=2up1 and 2min1];
\addplot[clr1!30] fill between[of=2up2 and 2min2];
\addplot[clr1!30] fill between[of=2up3 and 2min3];
\legend{method 1,method 2}
    \draw   ( 5,0) -- ++ (0,-14)
            (10,0) -- ++ (0,-14);
\node[X]   at ( 2.5,-12) {$\alpha$};
\node[X]   at ( 7.5,-12) {$\beta$};
\node[X]   at (12.5,-12) {$\gamma$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
            }

\subfloat[]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel={y axis},
    ymin=0,ymax=80,
            ]
\addplot+[name path=min1,draw=none] coordinates
    {(1,7.31) (2,14.62) (3,21.94) (4,28.90) };
\addplot+[name path=min2,draw=none] coordinates
    {(6,10.68) (7,21.37) (8,31.88) (9,42.30) };
\addplot+[name path=min3,draw=none] coordinates
    {(11,16.44) (12,32.65) (13,48.77) (14,64.42) };
%
\addplot+[name path=avg1,color=clr5] coordinates
    {(1,7.42) (2,14.78) (3,22.14) (4,29.12) };
\addplot+[name path=avg2,color=clr5] coordinates
    {(6,10.82) (7,21.56) (8,32.11) (9,42.56) };
\addplot+[name path=avg3,color=clr5] coordinates
    {(11,16.59) (12,32.86) (13,49.00) (14,64.72) };
%
\addplot+[name path=up1,draw=none] coordinates
    {(1,7.53) (2,14.94) (3,22.33) (4,29.34) };
\addplot+[name path=up2,draw=none] coordinates
    {(6,10.95) (7,21.75) (8,32.34) (9,42.81) };
\addplot+[name path=up3,draw=none] coordinates
    {(11,16.74) (12,33.07) (13,49.26) (14,65.02) };
\addplot+[name path=2min1,draw=none] coordinates
    {(1,6.34) (2,13.39) (3,20.84) (4,28.26) };
\addplot+[name path=2min2,draw=none] coordinates
    {(6,10.00) (7,20.79) (8,31.47) (9,42.45) };
\addplot+[name path=2min3,draw=none] coordinates
    {(11,15.78) (12,32.33) (13,48.85) (14,65.36) };
%
\addplot+[name path=2avg1,color=clr2] coordinates
    {(1,7.44) (2,14.87) (3,22.31) (4,29.75) };
\addplot+[name path=2avg2,color=clr2] coordinates
    {(6,10.90) (7,21.79) (8,32.69) (9,43.58) };
\addplot+[name path=2avg3,color=clr2, ] coordinates
    {(11,16.61) (12,33.23) (13,49.84) (14,66.46) };
\addplot+[name path=2up1,draw=none] coordinates
    {(1,8.48) (2,16.35) (3,23.78) (4,31.23) };
\addplot+[name path=2up2,draw=none] coordinates
    {(6,11.80) (7,22.80) (8,33.90) (9,44.72) };
\addplot+[name path=2up3,draw=none] coordinates
    {(11,17.45) (12,34.12) (13,50.84) (14,67.55) };
\legend{method 1,method 2}
    \draw   ( 5,0) -- ++ (0,-14)
            (10,0) -- ++ (0,-14);
\node[X]   at ( 2.5,-12) {$\alpha$};
\node[X]   at ( 7.5,-12) {$\beta$};
\node[X]   at (12.5,-12) {$\gamma$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\hfill
\subfloat[]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel={y axis},
    ymin=0,ymax=80,
            ]
\addplot+[name path=min1,color=clr6!30,draw=none] coordinates {(1,7.2617232766601) (2,14.4680749092339) (3,21.6871818386066) (4,28.6235229337246) };
\addplot+[name path=min2,color=clr6!30,draw=none] coordinates {(6,10.4466564581329) (7,20.7550717502665) (8,31.2585866911777) (9,41.2167137846509) };
\addplot+[name path=min3,color=clr6!30,draw=none] coordinates {(11,16.236658999683) (12,32.4366974815625) (13,48.5535530086021) (14,64.2037285516522) };
\addplot+[name path=avg1,color=clr6, ] coordinates {(1,7.38116000000005) (2,14.6323366666664) (3,21.88 74 43 33 33 32 7) (4,28.8513966666664) };
\addplot+[name path=avg2,color=clr6, ] coordinates {(6,10.5811433333332) (7,20.9419566666662) (8,31.4898933333331) (9,41.4746999999999) };
\addplot+[name path=avg3,color=clr6, ] coordinates {(11,16.3936566666664) (12,32.6571433333333) (13,48.8214366666666) (14,64.5108633333335) };
\addplot+[name path=up1,color=clr6!30,draw=none] coordinates {(1,7.50059672334) (2,14.7965984240989) (3,22.0877048280588) (4,29.0792703996082) };
\addplot+[name path=up2,color=clr6!30,draw=none] coordinates {(6,10.7156302085335) (7,21.1288415830659) (8,31.7211999754885) (9,41.7326862153489) };
\addplot+[name path=up3,color=clr6!30,draw=none] coordinates {(11,16.5506543336498) (12,32.8775891851041) (13,49.0893203247311) (14,64.8179981150148) };
\addplot+[name path=2min1,color=clr3!30,draw=none] coordinates {(1,6.35327922467375) (2,13.2744239387005) (3,20.2717978423772) (4,27.7248848189148) };
\addplot+[name path=2min2,color=clr3!30,draw=none] coordinates {(6,9.58669927080587) (7,20.1057231186807) (8,30.76238054228) (9,41.2581975426363) };
\addplot+[name path=2min3,color=clr3!30,draw=none] coordinates {(11,15.7537659514287) (12,32.3582144477746) (13,48.8744039249612) (14,65.5343006488307) };
\addplot+[name path=2avg1,color=clr3, ] coordinates {(1,7.40901502504168) (2,14.8180300500835) (3,22.2270450751252) (4,29.6360601001671) };
\addplot+[name path=2avg2,color=clr3, ] coordinates {(6,10.6325369738338) (7,21.2650739476677) (8,31.8976109215017) (9,42.5301478953357) };
\addplot+[name path=2avg3,color=clr3, ] coordinates {(11,16.6337868480723) (12,33.2675736961447) (13,49.9013605442172) (14,66.5351473922894) };
\addplot+[name path=2up1,color=clr3!30,draw=none] coordinates {(1,8.46475082540961) (2,16.3616361614665) (3,24.1822923078732) (4,31.5472353814194) };
\addplot+[name path=2up2,color=clr3!30,draw=none] coordinates {(6,11.6783746768617) (7,22.4244247766547) (8,33.0328413007234) (9,43.8020982480351) };
\addplot+[name path=2up3,color=clr3!30,draw=none] coordinates {(11,17.5138077447159) (12,34.1769329445148) (13,50.9283171634732) (14,67.5359941357481) };
\addlegendimage{color=clr3,thick} \addlegendentry{method 1}
\legend{method 1,method 2}
    \draw   ( 5,0) -- ++ (0,-14)
            (10,0) -- ++ (0,-14);
\node[X]   at ( 2.5,-12) {$\alpha$};
\node[X]   at ( 7.5,-12) {$\beta$};
\node[X]   at (12.5,-12) {$\gamma$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
            }
     \caption{bla bla bla}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

in above *mwe* the following changes are made to your version *mwe*:

- used is recent `pgplots` version (v 1.16)
- in `\pgfplotsset` are colected common definitions of diagrams
- defined are common `y label style` and `x label style` so the size of images now have the same size
- removed are all `\resizebox`es
- defined are common image size (with `width=0.48\linewidth,)
- in the first three diagrams i rounded coordinates to two decimal digits. defining them with accuracy of the 11 decimal digits has no sense
- for sub figures are used environments `\subfloat` from the package `\subfig`. package `subfigure` is obsolete long time ago ...`

obtained result is:

[image]