# Align pgfplots horizontally

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to align the pgfplots seen in the picture below.

[image]

I already tried with `\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=3em,align=right}}`, but as you can see, the plots are still not aligned.

The code I used is listed below. I uploaded the necessary files here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mlyaVNN9au6o-B-z9bHRpirUSnu3cxsT , if you want to play around with it.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
%%german umlauts and localization
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%%figures etc.
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}

%%fonts:
%Times like
\usepackage{txfonts}  %supplies virtual text roman fonts using Adobe Times % needs to be loaded AFTER amsmath (because otherwise \iint is defined twice)
\usepackage{siunitx}

%%tikz
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale} %augments the \includegraphics command to accept tikzimages and scale them
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,shadows}


\pgfplotsset{yticklabel style={text width=3em,align=right}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{a18_0.tikz}
        \caption{Geschätzter Weg für $\sigma_{\Delta v_{BE}}^{2} >> \sigma_{\Delta v_{IG}}^{2}$}
        \label{fig:a618_1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{a18_3.tikz}
        \caption{Geschätzter Weg für $\sigma_{\Delta v_{BE}}^{2} << \sigma_{\Delta v_{IG}}^{2}$}
        \label{fig:a618_2}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption{Geschätzter Weg}  
    \label{fig:a618_Weg}    
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{a18_1.tikz}
        \caption{Geschätzte Geschwindigkeit für $\sigma_{\Delta v_{BE}}^{2} >> \sigma_{\Delta v_{IG}}^{2}$}
        \label{fig:a618_3}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width = 1\textwidth]{a18_4.tikz}
        \caption{Geschätzte Geschwindigkeit für $\sigma_{\Delta v_{BE}}^{2} << \sigma_{\Delta v_{IG}}^{2}$}
        \label{fig:a618_4}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption{Geschwindigkeitsverläufe}  
    \label{fig:a618_v}  
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you are using separate suvfugures, groupplot isn't an option.  Instead you need a constant distance from the axis (origin) to the left border on each plot.  [axis trim left] will set the distanc e to zero. ` \path (-1cm,0);` will add a 1cm distance where used.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321470/subfloat-and-pgfplot-with-trim and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473507/how-to-set-up-perfectly-multiple-figures-when-using-subfigure-and-tikz

Comment: (i) you can not include `tikz` files with `includegraphicds`, (ii) we haven't any information about your `tikz` images. are they have equal width? does in their positioning is consider only diagram (with `trim axis left`), etc.